# No output when accessing Laravel database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**This is my `database.php` file:**

```
        'mysql' => array(
                    'driver'    => 'mysql',
                    'host'      => 'localhost',
                    'database'  => 'learning_laravel',
                    'username'  => 'forge',
                    'password'  => 'bomb',
                    'charset'   => 'utf8',
                    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    'prefix'    => '',
```

**My `route.php` file:**

```
        <?php

        Route::get('/',function(){
        $username=DB::table('username')->get();
        return $username;
        });
```

I created a database called learning_laravel and created a table called username and given input to it but i am not getting any output.

When i open localhost:8000/ by typing php artisan serve this is the output i get.

**My Output file**:

```
    Database[]not configured
        $connections = $this->app['config']['database.connections'];

    if (is_null($config = array_get($connections, $name)))
    {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Database [$name] not configured.");
    }
```

Comment: In `app/config/app.php` find the line `'debug' => false` and change it to `'debug' => true` You'll now get detailed error reporting

Comment: @DamienPirsy there should be output, if you return a collection object Laravel will convert it to json

Comment: Have you set your default database option to mysql?

Comment: Are u sure that the credentials are correct?  `forge` is the default username value. Look in your phpmyadmin to see if `forge`-user exists. Then try `root` as username with no password. Also check if this is set: `default' => 'mysql'`, in your `database.php` file (row 29).

Comment: could you check the app()->environment(), maybe you are looking at the wrong configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't your database connection configured.

You can find config in following file `app/config/database.php` with example content

```
'default' => 'mysql', //your database name according to prefix in connections subarray
'connections' => array(
     'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'your database name here',
            'username'  => 'your username here',
            'password'  => 'your password here',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_bin',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```